# retrieve image in post with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am developing the server side php code of a mobile application using PHP with code igniter. As of now, I would like to allow users to upload images to Amazon S3 to and further allow the user to retrieve the Amazon Cloud Front url of the image that they uploaded. However, I am stuck on the image uploading part of the code. I currently get post input parameters the following way:

```
$userName    = $this->input->post('userName');

    if (!empty($userName))
    {
                ...
    }
```

When I search on google, all I find are scripts on how to upload images from multipart forms for example, or forms in general: [Like in this link, for example](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease--net-31)

We do not use any form at this point in our app. Is there any other way to do so in php+codeigniter? Is there a similar CI way to get images from post?

EDIT: We are also thinking of uploading the images directly from our application to Amazon S3 and then storing the amazon s3 url in our database, which would also reduce traffic to our server.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out CodeIgniter's [file upload class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).